# Exception of PostgreSQL with C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to use PostgreSQL with C# (not asp.net) via `Npqsql`, I created a table with the name `GenData` with SQL;

```
CREATE TABLE gendata
(
  empname text NOT NULL,
  pyrll text NOT NULL,
  contracno text,
  expird date,
  dtbrth date,
  plbrth text,
  cid text,
  passport text,
  jndt date,
  postn text,
  dept text,
  hmtwn text,
  familymen numeric,
  contno text,
  CONSTRAINT gendata_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pyrll)
)
```

I tried to insert to the table with the following code:

```
String sql = String.Format("INSERT INTO GenData VALUES ({0},{1},{2},'{3}',{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13});"
                    ,textBox1.Text
                    ,textBox2.Text
                    ,textBox3.Text
                    ,textBox4.Text
                    ,textBox5.Text
                    ,textBox6.Text
                    ,textBox7.Text
                    ,textBox8.Text
                    ,textBox9.Text
                    ,textBox10.Text
                    ,textBox11.Text
                    ,textBox12.Text
                    ,textBox13.Text
                    ,textBox14.Text);
```

But I always get an exception like:
[image]

Comment: Why are you quoting the fourth column only? I think you should be quoting all your columns, except perhaps the numeric ones.

Comment: Before you delve any further, you should **really** stop and read up on SQL injection attacks. You should not be taking raw user input and feeding it directly into a SQL statement, but instead be using parameterized queries.

Comment: I know about SQL injection & parametrized statements, I do that for testing purpose only.

Comment: @Ahmed It's still a bad habit, and is best not posted on public sites where other people might use your code as an example. As you can see from the responses, it also distracts everybody from the problem at hand. Additionally, "just for testing" or prototype code tends to turn into production code when it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not using SQL Parameters, but directly embed values into the string (which is considered quite bad practice), you should follow SQL syntax. In your particular situation, you should wrap all string parameters into `'`.

Better way is to use [`SQLParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) class to allow .NET perform all necessary transformations on input data, escape the data to avoid sql-injections and so on. I'm not quite familiar with Npgsql, but I'm almost sure it follows the same guidelines as the other .NET database providers, so you should be able to use the `SQLParameter` class the same way.

Comment: in Npgsql it is called NpgsqlParameter